# How can I make my Rails app / codebase customisable to deploy it as different sites

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app which implements a job board that is specific to a technology (Ruby on Rails). The app is working great and **I'd like to clone this app and use the same code to create job boards for other technologies** (Java, Javascript, etc.).

These apps will need to share 90% percent of the code, and **I'd like to make some parts customisable**:

1. Images and "theme" of the app. Layout will be the same but each of the apps will have different images for the logo. Also, I'd like to be able to change some colors to make each app look different.
2. i18n translation files in `config/locales`.
3. Some other configurations like the name of the S3 bucket where logos are updated or the ID of the mailing list in Mailchimp. I thought about using ENV variables for this (and something like [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv))

Do you have experience with something like this? How would you make each of these things customisable?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I created 3 environments for 3 clients. 
It allows to deploy the same course to 3 different domains with separate databases.
Name of layout file, translation file, configurations are based on client's environment files.